# Owl Carousel with Magnific Popup - Popup not even displaying, not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, magnific-popup

I'm using Magnific Popup for my Owl Carousel Slider. I just want the images to pop-up on screen. However, it doesn't seem to be working. The only thing it does it when I click the images, it opens up its src link. But I just want the Magnific Popup. Am I importing the files wrong? Am i formatting wrong? I've tried so much and can't seem to get the Magnific Popup to even display...

**HTML/PHP**

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme details_banner">
    @forelse($home_images as $image_model)
    @php
    $real_image = public_path('uploads/frontend/home/' . $image_model->name);
    $image = asset('public/uploads/frontend/home/' . $image_model->name);
    if (!file_exists($real_image)) {
    $image=DEFAULT_IMG;
    }
    @endphp    
    
    <a class="popup1" href="<?php echo $image ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
     @empty
    <a a class="popup1" href="<?php echo DEFAULT_IMG ?>"><img src="<?php echo DEFAULT_IMG ?>"/></a>
     @endforelse
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.popup1').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
            closeOnBgClick :true,
            enableEscapeKey: true
        });    
    });
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/Magnific-Popup-master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
```

**I put this at the top of my file**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('public/frontend/css/owl.carousel.min.css')}}" />
<link href="{{asset('public/backend/css/jquery-confirm.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/Magnific-Popup-master/dist/magnific-popup.css" media="screen"/>
```

Comment: sidenote: you could try and open up the developer console on your browser, to see if everything is working fine, usually when you miss some library of sorts, it'll show some errors in there

Comment: Ah you're right, I didn't think of looking there..."magnificPopup is not a function". Guessing I didn't import the files right

Comment: yes, load everything first, jquery -> other library -> then on your script. initialize the libraries that you need. just put the inclusion of files on top of the script tag first

Comment: Yeah it just started working when I put the jquery link above everything else. Can't believe I spent all day figuring this out. Thank you, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by putting these 2 lines above my Magnific Function

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
```